# Explain this small Regex operation, meant to enable better string matching

Tags: javascript, regex, string

This regex is meant to enable string matching for strings with the same prefixes. This is meant to be a better solution than simply doing `text.startsWith(commandPrefix + 'anim ')`

Here is the regex solution:

```
var prefix = commandPrefix.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&');
return text.test("/^" + prefix + "anim(?=\s|$)/");
```

`commandPrefix` will be configured by the user and will be a symbol in most cases, such as `/` or `!` etc.

I understand the gist of it, but am looking for an in-depth explanation so I can improve on this.

Do let me know if this question is better suited for CodeReview :) Thanks

Comment: What exactly is it that you don't understand?

Comment: @FelixKling My current understanding is that the  `commandPrefix` is being replaced with a custom prefix which than is added to a regex in the next statement. But the `anim(...)` part is doing something again. my understanding is very superficial, and possibly wrong.

Comment: `anim` literally matches the character sequence `anim`. `(?=\s|$)` matches if the following character is a white space character or the end of the string.

Comment: And why is `commandPrefix` converted? Why can't we just do it as `text.test(commandPrefix + "anim(?=\s|$)/");` ?

Comment: `commandPrefix` is converted because it's being sanitized of special regular expression characters. You don't want the user to use characters in the prefix that will mess up the regular expression.

Comment: I see, that makes sense. and that `/^` append to the same is for the regex itself. And can we improve on this regex-based solution? Perhaps tidy it up? (Post as an answer so I can accept it :) )